# detect new or modified files with python

Tags: python, linux, file, filesystems

I'm trying to detect when a new file is created a directory or when an existing file is modified in a directory.

I tried searching for a script that would do this (preferably in python or bash) but came up short. My environment is linux with Python 2.6

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415856/how-to-detect-new-or-modified-files)

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: Linux with Python 2.6. As mentioned above. Specifically, Fedora Core 2. Thanks.

Comment: @Jake: Do not comment on your own question.  Please UPDATE your question with new facts and delete your comment.

Comment: He commented on a comment, not on his question... and update?  Why, it was all there (except for the Fedora bit, but why would that be significant...).

Answer (score 13):

You can use `gio` which is the Filesystem part of GLib (In GLib's python bindings)

```
import gio

def directory_changed(monitor, file1, file2, evt_type):
   if (evt_type in (gio.FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_CREATED,
       gio.FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_DELETED)):
       print "Changed:", file1, file2, evt_type

gfile = gio.File(".")
monitor = gfile.monitor_directory(gio.FILE_MONITOR_NONE, None)
monitor.connect("changed", directory_changed)
```

however, your program must be running a GLib mainloop for the events to arrive. One quick way to test that is by using:

```
import glib
ml = glib.MainLoop()
ml.run()
```

GLib is a high-level library which is well suited for Applications. You don't have to care about which underlying system it uses for the file monitoring.

---

I now see you use Fedora Core 2. Really version 2? That might be too old to use GIO in GLib. Pyinotify that has been mentioned might be a better solution, although less portable.

Comment: Too GNOME-ish! I don't like that, it's just an unnecessary dependency.

Comment: Andrey: It is just GLib. Do you have it installed (if you're using Linux) or not?

Comment: @kaizer.se I'm a Linux minimalist, I use `wmii` as a window manager and don't like various GNOME stuff. (But actually yes, I have `glib` installed because of `udev`, `avahi`, `mc`, ... ;)

Comment: @Andrey: You may be right in that GLib is too big. It is a convenient interface, but to very many things.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Linux, you may try [`pyinotify`](http://trac.dbzteam.org/pyinotify) that acts like an object-oriented wrapper around the [`inotify(7)`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) system calls. The project website contains quite  straightforward tutorials and examples.

Comment: +1, Another interesting solution

Answer (score 1):

If you can use PyQt, there's QFileSystemWatcher that does just this.

Answer (score 0):

There are also [Python bindings for gamin](http://people.gnome.org/~veillard/gamin/python.html).