# python script call on user modification or adding of files to linux directory

Tags: python, linux, filesystems, directory

I have a directory of files on my Ubuntu machine. I run python 2.6. All of these files are represented in a database for purposes of sorting, searching, locating, etc. I'd like to trigger a python script every time a file is added or modified to update said database.

basically, upon adding, moving, deleting, or renaming a file, a script would be called to make `update` queries to SQL database.

similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618853/detect-new-or-modified-files-with-python). however, I would like to directly feed such a file into a script - plus I was confused - pynotify or gio? what can detect deleted files? doesn't seem like these are best.

any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) to run a script that gets passed the new filenames.