# New file creation detection using Python in Windows

Tags: python, file

Is there a possibility to detect if a new file is created on **Windows** using Python programming language?
Maybe my questions sounds meaningless, but I need this information to develop a program that can detect if a new file is created on my computer by a given application (maybe a virus, or any other benign application).

Comment: maybe [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) is what you need?

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: do you want to check the whole C drive?

Comment: @mata Wow ! Thank you a lot ! That is a very interesting point to start with ! I hope I can get some similar useful information.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, even more, the whole computer where I installed only Windows

Comment: A similar question but for Linux OS. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1618853/2382792

Comment: @begueradj, how long do you think  this is going to take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A script to check all files on your specified folder/drive and check for changes to the names or new files added.

```
import os
import pickle
from multiprocessing import Process

def scanner(root_dir, output):
    temp = set()
#if not os.path.isfile(output):  # if output does not exist create it
    with open(output, 'a'):
        pass

    files = os.walk(root_dir)  # go through all dirs and sub dirs
    for root, dirs, f in files:
        if f:
            temp.update(f)  # add all "f" files to the set
    with open(output, 'rb') as data:
        if os.path.getsize(output) > 0:  # if the file has data, it is not the first run so load and compare
            b = pickle.load(data)
            print " Deleted files {}".format(b-temp)  # if a file name has been changed been deleted
            print "Amended or New files {}".format(temp-b)  # if a file name has been changed or one added
    with open(output, 'wb') as data:  # write current files and save to output
        pickle.dump(temp, data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # start process for each drive
    p1 = Process(target=scanner, args=("/path1", "data.pickle"))
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=scanner, args=("/path2", "data1.pickle"))
    p2.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import subprocess as sp

class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_any_event(self, event):
        print(event.event_type, event.src_path)

    def on_created(self, event):
        print("on_created", event.src_path)
        print(event.src_path.strip())
        if((event.src_path).strip() == ".\test.xml"):        
            print("Execute your logic here!")
 
event_handler = MyHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, path='.', recursive=False)
observer.start()


while True:
    try:
        pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
```

1. pip install watchdog
2. Create a scheduled task for this script in the Task scheduler and monitor the folder where the file will be created.

Answer (score -1):

you would have to have/create a database of all files on the computer and scan through every possible name (go through all ASCII values for a char then ad add or increment the next char to a reasonable length) to see if it is there using this you could use the compare the old database and new database to see the changes

Edit: this could help [Browse files and subfolders in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817209/browse-files-and-subfolders-in-python)
(search in the C or default drive for everything and save its location)

Comment: This is almost certain to be too slow.

Comment: If windows had a easy way to do it wouldn't their virus software do it and not be required to scan

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think it is huge task, or even impossible, to list all the files that my operating system  (windows) is hosting.